# Is it possible to decorate parcel bundler dist folder?

Tags: javascript, npm, bundler, parceljs

When I compile code with parcel using the command `parcel src/index.html` its just generate all files inside dist folder, like this image below. But I need a decorated way to manage files after complete my website. I mean I need `img` folder for all the images inside `./dist/img/...` and also for css and js folder inside the dist folder.

> How can I archive something like in the **second image**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve your goal by using [custom packager](https://parceljs.org/packagers.html) and change the destination path due to AssetType.